# Exporting .qml file using QGIS API with specific categories

Tags: pyqgis, style, save, qml

I need to save a style file (.qml) that will only contain the "Symbology", "Labeling", "Forms" categories. With PyQGIS I can save a named style like this:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
path = f'C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\Save\\Directory\\{lyr.name()}.qml'
if lyr.type() == QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer:
    lyr.saveNamedStyle(path)
```

How can I save a .qml style file with a subset of style categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the style categories you wish to save after the `categories` keyword argument. It should go without saying that you just need to change the `path` variable for your own system.

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
path = f'C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\Save\\Directory\\{lyr.name()}.qml'
if lyr.type() == QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer:
    lyr.saveNamedStyle(path, categories = QgsMapLayer.Symbology | QgsMapLayer.Labeling | QgsMapLayer.Forms)
```

Tested in QGIS 3.20

You can read the docs [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aca5aecf2287023a11a925e928a7d225e) and [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ae44dba60c5814bec4a8180753d7faec4).